# (Simulink) External mode (Arduino Mega 2650) Logging Data (Saving To Workspace or To File)

Tags: arduino, save, external, simulink, workspace

I have a [MinSeg](http://minseg.com/), which is built upon an [Arduino Mega 2650](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560).

I am connecting to the Arduino board using Simulink (in External mode), and
I am attempting to continuously log data on the Arduino Mega.

**Problem**:
When I start a run and later end the simulation,
the To Workspace block has only saved the last made sample.

Guidelines are provided [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/texasinstrumentsc2000/examples/parameter-tuning-and-signal-logging-with-serial-external-mode.html); however, they seem convoluted.
Is there no way to just continuously log data?

[This guy](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/258050-simulink-to-workspace-block-collects-only-one-or-two-data-points-running-in-external-mode) also had the same problem,
but said he fixed it with an earlier version.
I feel like some setting has changed;
I can't imagine why things would have become *more* difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by changing MATLAB release from 2015b to 2017b.